# Regex in validation rule to start with the alphabet QC followed by 3 numbers

Tags: regular-expressions

Example - QC578

I need to create a VR using regex that allows user to enter only the input that starts with QC in caps followed by 3 numbers.

Answer (score 0):

That would look like this:

```
NOT(REGEX(Field, '^QC\\D{3}$'))
```

If you want to option to allow the field to be null:

```
NOT(OR(ISBLANK(Field), REGEX(Field, '^QC\\D{3}$')))
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will work for you

```
^(?:QC[0-9]{3})$
```